# DB2 how to delete from two tables

Tags: sql, db2

I'm trying to delete records from two tables, can someone help me correct my query. Thanks.

This is what I tried:

```
DELETE FROM 
           table1 x, 
           table2 xx
       WHERE x.id ='123' AND xx.id = '123'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from table1 x where x.id ='123'

delete from table2 xx where xx.id = '123'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not delete variables which are include two table. You should delete one by one.

```
DELETE FROM table1 where id = '123';
DELETE FROM table2 where id = '123';
```

Comment: or you should join two table firstly.